# PowerApps: How to change the selected value of a drop down list via expression

Tags: powerapps

I'm looking for a way to change the selected value of a drop down list through the OnSelect of a button. I would imagine this expression for the OnSelect would have worked:

```
dropDownList1.Selected.Value = "01"
```

...but it doesn't. I get no error or warning message. It just doesn't seem to do anything.

The drop down list has the following values: ["12","01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11"]

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

- dropDownList1

  - `OnChange`: `Set(varDDValue, dropDownList1.Selected.Value)`
- button

  - `OnSelect`: `Set(varDDValue, "whatevertheheckyouwant")` (must be a value that is present in the dropdown `Items` property)
- dropDownList1

  - `Default`: `varDDValue`

Comment: it's not working for me

Comment: I was trying to set the value using a button. Doing `Set(varDDValue, cmbApprovalStatus.Selected.Value); Set(varDDValue, "Approve")` doesn't work.